# By proof show that the following statements hold ($A, B, C$ are arbitrary propositions)

Tags: logic

> By proof show that the following statements hold ($A, B, C$ are
> arbitrary propositions):
>
> $\{A\Rightarrow B, A\Rightarrow C\} \vdash A \Rightarrow (B\wedge C)$

I tried almost every axiom, but I always failed. Here are the Axioms I used:

[image]

Comment: Different people use different axioms. What axioms are you using? What infernece rules?

Comment: @ancientmathematician: The post is edited to include that.

Comment: What about using the 4th axiom?

Comment: Perhaps you can re-edit to tell us the rules of inference? I assume MP but these things matter.

Comment: Your axioms include the two you need to prove the Deduction Theorem. So it suffices to prove that $\{A\to B, A\to C, A\} \vdash (B\wedge C)$. Clearly $\{A\to B, A\to C, A\} \vdash B, \vdash C$. So now use the 4th axiom in the 1st column and MP twice.